# how can I set up a website to mirror whatever is pushed to git?

Tags: git, host, mirror

how can I set up a domain to mirror the files hosted on a git repository (github.com/nospampleasemam/dylanstestserver and dylanstestserver.com). The repository is of a website, so I want to host the files stored in the repository, not just mirror the files for download.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From that web server, you can set a cron job to "pull" frequently.

Comment: this looks like the simplest solution, but I can't quite seem to figure it out on my own. do you think you could walk me through it or point me to some references? I can't find anything that is making it clear.

Comment: So you are not sure how to use cron?

Comment: i tried adding a cron job 'git pull git@github.com/nospampleasemam/dylanstestserver.git' and made sure it's run, but I have no idea where the files are ending up? I've searched but can't seem to turn up anything

Comment: Try this: cd /var/www/html/yourwebroot && git pull git@github.com/nospampleasemam/dylanstestserver.git

Answer (score 0):

You can [use a hook](http://linux.subogero.com/934/i-am-a-webmaster/) to checkout the repository at the server side.

(there is a typo on the linked page.... it is `$REF`, not `$RE`)

Comment: this looks like it could be elegant, but I'm a bit confused on how to implement it as I am using hostgator.com, and don't have shell access to the host, or at least, i haven't accessed it that way yet. should I try to use this approach over ssh?

Comment: @Nona Urbiz: which os are you on?

Comment: im using ubuntu? the host is linux as well

Comment: You can use the `post-commit` hook *on your computer*. Install `ncftp` package in ubuntu, and create a shell script `.git/hooks/pre-commit` to run `ncftpput -u username -p password hostname /localdirectory /removedirectory`